# @loadable/server pass the whole stats JSON to eval('require')(modulePath)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering, loadable-component

I'm trying to setup SSR for react app with `@loadable/components`. I setup all based on docs with babel and webpack plugins. When I try to run `node server.js` it runs ok but when I open a browser and throws the following error (into node console):

```sh
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:118:11)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:3)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at smartRequire (/Users/max/Documents/repos/app/node_modules/@loadable/server/lib/util.js:44:25)
    at new ChunkExtractor (/Users/max/Documents/repos/app/node_modules/@loadable/server/lib/ChunkExtractor.js:181:50)
    at renderer (webpack://app/./node_modules/@MYSCOPE/elm/dist/elm.esm.js?:3619:19)
    at eval (webpack://app/./src/server.tsx?:64:90)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

As you can see there is @MYSCOPE in the traceback which holds some of my internal packages (if it matters).

`@loadable/server/lib/util.js` is the following function:

[image]

And when I try to `console.log(modulePath)` on line **42** I see a whole stats JSON output which seems wrong and I should get a single module path (as I understand).

Any help?

I can share some specific parts of my configuration files if needed. Because I see my own package in console output seems like something is wrong with it's build (it works perfectly on the client-side with cjs build), but having full stats object as module path is very confusing.

**UPD:** Demo https://www.dropbox.com/s/9r947cgg4qvqbu4/loadable-test.zip?dl=0

Run

```
yarn
yarn dev:server
# go to localhost:3000 and see the error in console
```

to rebuild:

```
yarn
yarn dev:build-client
yarn dev:build-server
yarn dev:server # go to localhost:3000
```

Comment: can you provide a demo?

Comment: It's hard to create a short demo from the big project with all its configurations... but I will try to extract smth into the demo

Comment: @AmerllicA here is a demo https://www.dropbox.com/s/9r947cgg4qvqbu4/loadable-test.zip?dl=0 Run yarn -> dev:server and go to localhost:3000 and you see the same error in console. Run dev:build-client and then dev:build-server to rebuild application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `statsFile` option passed to `ChunkExtractor` expects a path to the `loadable-stats.json` file, not the actual JSON content of it. By doing `require('../loadable-stats.json')`, webpack actually resolve the JSON during build time and assign it to the `loadableJson` variable.

You can change your `loadableJson` as follow:

```
import path from 'path';

const loadableJson = path.resolve(__dirname, '../bundle_client/loadable-stats.json');
```

This will solve the problem you had on your question. But, if you only do this, you will notice that you have another problem. Loadable by default assumes that your entry chunk name is `main`. This is not the case in your demo, as you have set the entry chunk name to be `app` instead.

```
entry: {
    app: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/index.tsx']
},
```

To solve this, simply tell loadable about your `entrypoints` names by passing an array to the `ChunkExtractor` contructor as such:

```
    const extractor = new ChunkExtractor({
        statsFile: loadableJson,
        entrypoints: ["app"], // name of your entry chunk
    });
```

That's it, everything should now be working properly!

If it helps, I set up the demo on GitHub so you can easily see the changes I made [here](https://github.com/jackyef/loadable-ssr-implementation-fix/commit/b869de5d96a02f334b5266bbcc78cfe276b31ba3).

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why I thought that it should accept a JSON instead of a path...